# Getting Expression must evaluate to a node-set when trying to get first node value in internet explorer

Tags: xml, xpath

I have below xml format:

```
<tcm:Data>
    <tcm:Title>Test</tcm:Title>
    <tcm:Type>Normal</tcm:Type>
    <tcm:Schema xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="Test" xlink:href="tcm:233-190439-8" IsMandatory="false"/>
    <tcm:Content>
        <GeneralContent>
            <Title>
                <TitleText>Test</TitleText>
            </Title>
            <Summary>Test</Summary>
            <Artwork xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Test" xlink:href="tcm:233-195404"/>
        </GeneralContent>
        <test1></test1>
    </tcm:Content>
</tcm:Data>
```

I am using below xpath to get my first node after the content

```
var firstNode = local-name(//tcm:Data/tcm:Content/node())
```

If I check in XMLSpy I get my required result i.e. "GeneralContent" above code works fine in firefox, however getting above error in Internet explorer.

Please suggest what could be the reason.

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

Well you haven't shown which XPath implementation and API you use with Internet Explorer. Usually people use a version of MSXML as the XPath implementation and the API exposed by MSXML only has two methods `selectSingleNode` and `selectNodes` which indeed require the XPath expression passed in as an argument to return a node set and not a string value as calling `local-name(...)` would do. So with MSXML you can't evaluate XPath expressions returning a primitive value (i.e. string, number, boolean) unless you put the XPath expression into a complete XSLT stylesheet and run that.